# All incoming connections use my main router's IP (2 router setup)

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I'm using a two router setup with the following hardware:

Netgear WNDR3400V2 - 192.168.1.1 - DD-WRT

Belkin F9K1105 v1 - 192.168.1.50 - Stock FW

The Belkin is set up as a switch, to which I have a webserver connected.

[Internet] -> Netgear -> Belkin -> Server

When connecting internally, it logs my IP appropriately (e.g. 192.168.1.51)
When connecting **externally**, all IPs are seen as 192.168.1.1 (The main router's IP)

This, of course, works just fine when not behind a second router, but unfortunately my current setup is out of necessity.

I was wondering if I could get some specific instruction on how to be able to properly 'see' external IP addresses from the server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you could switch Netgear and Belkin, there would be no such problem.

Comment: Could you explain why that would fix the problem? (FIrmware, I'm guessing?) The current setup is preferred as the Netgear is simply the better general-use router for the rest of my house (and has much better QoS than the belkin), but I can try the switch when there's less internet usage going on.

Comment: DD-WRT routers are easily programmable, all you have to do is to make sure that the firewall configuration does **not** contain a rule imposing *MASQUERADE* for your Web server. Can you control the firewall on the Netgear?

Comment: I can give it a shot, sure. So far, the setup on it is more or less stock DD-WRT.

Comment: Do you have DD-WRT on the Netgear as well? Sorry, perhaps I missed it...

Comment: Oh wait, I botched my line breaks in the question. I have DD-WRT on the netgear ONLY, and stock on the belkin. Sorry about that.

Comment: What you've explained doesn't make sense, unless the belkin is being used as a router (with NAT) and not a switch.

Comment: I have an eth cable going from the netgear to a LAN port on the belkin. Could be that that router doesn't want to function as a switch, I suppose. Unless I'm doing something wrong here (in which case, please correct me).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the default iptables rules that DD-WRT sets up.

Removing the MASQUERADE line in POSTROUTING fixes the issue for me, external connections are no longer appearing as my main router's internal IP.

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
SNAT       0    --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            to:1.1.1.1 
RETURN     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast
```

This removes the first element in the above list:

`iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1`

More info on the above fix can be found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/40swj2/firewall_log_shows_router_ip_for_all_incoming/cyxaz3t/

Now, everything should work fine.

Side note: If you can no longer access your services via external IP from an internal IP, you may need to do one or both of the following (I required both):

1. Make sure to uncheck "Filter WAN NAT Redirection" on "DD-WRT -> Security -> Firewall"
2. Run the following:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`

Replacing both occurences of 192.168.1.0/24 with whatever's relevant to your setup.

To make this easier, I recommend just saving this in the Firewall script under "Administration -> Commands"

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```